# Change InnerHTML based on screen position?

Tags: javascript, html

I need help with a project. I have a reviews section of our website that I'd like to have a button display when the user scrolls to a certain point and perform the following actions:

1. Button shows when `#comments` hits the top of the viewport, and `innerHTML = 'LEAVE A REVIEW'`
2. When user clicks on button, `#review_form` scrolls into view using `scrollIntoView()` method.
3. This will take the user to the `#review_form` div which the browser will recognize that the `#review_form` div is now at the top of the browser viewport which it will change `LEAVE A REVIEW` to `SCROLL TO TOP`
4. I haven't gotten here yet, but I'd like to change the `onClick` function from `scrollIntoView()` to actually scroll to the top of the page.

My question is, am I going about this the right way with the following code? the `else if` statement is not working. I also don't know how to change the `onClick` of a button.

Do I need to create two separate `<button>`s?

**HTML:**

```
<button onClick="scrollToComment()" id="scroll-btn"></button>

<div id="comments">
  //a bunch of reviews and comments go here
</div>

<div id="review_form">
  //review form here
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    const comments = document.querySelector('#comments');
    const commentsPosition = comments.getBoundingClientRect();
    const scrollBtn = document.querySelector('#scroll-btn');
    const review = document.querySelector('#review_form');
    const reviewPosition = review.getBoundingClientRect();

     if( commentsPosition.top < -1 && commentsPosition.top < 1 ) {
        scrollBtn.style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('scroll-btn').innerHTML = 'LEAVE A REVIEW';
    }

    else if( reviewPosition.top < -1 && reviewPosition.top < 1 ) {

        //not working:
        document.getElementById('scroll-btn').innerHTML = 'BACK TO TOP';
    }

    else {

        scrollBtn.style.display = 'none';

    }
});

// scroll to review form
function scrollToComment() {
    var button = document.querySelector('#review_form');
    button.scrollIntoView();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your if condition is weird :
`if( commentsPosition.top < -1 && commentsPosition.top < 1 )`;

If `commentsPosition.top` is less than -1 it's also less than 1, so this part `&& commentsPosition.top < 1` is not needed.

Now, considering that `#review_form` is after `#comments` in your HTML I'm assuming that your review form is placed below your comments section. So your `else if` block cannot be reached, because if your `else if` is true, that implies that your `if` is also true. And if your `if` is false, then your `else if` is false too.

That's a first point you can look at.

If you want to change your click function dynamically you could do it like this and remove the onClick from your html:

```
const scrollBtn = document.querySelector('#scroll-btn');
scrollBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(condition){
        //scroll to review form
    } else if (condition){
        //scroll to top
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Harianrhod! I appreciate the explaination, as I'm new and learning JS. I'll tweak some code and use the EventListener('click') as well, that's a huge help.